# Data from firestore being collected in model but not not able to use this data in view

Tags: arrays, swift, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to get some data from a firebase firestore and put each document into its own index in an array.
Model:

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore
import Firebase
import SwiftUI


    public class MatchModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var match: [Matches] = []
@Published var db = Firestore.firestore()

func getData()  {
  
            
    self.db.collection("matches").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            
        } else {
            
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                //print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                //print("\(document.documentID) and \(document["sport"] as? String ?? "")")
                
                let uidX = document["uid"] as? String ?? ""
                let timeX = document["time"] as? String ?? ""
                let sportX = document["sport"] as? String ?? ""
                let numPlayersX = document["numPlayers"] as? Int ?? 40
                
                self.match.append(Matches(dID: document.documentID, uid: uidX, time: timeX, sport: sportX, numPlayers: numPlayersX))
                
                
                
            }
            
            
        }
        
    }


 }
```

which happens successfully(able to print each part of the array with the correct values) but when I make an instance of the model in my view and look at the filled array, the array is empty and nothing shows up
View:

```
struct AvailableMatches: View {

@ObservedObject var model = MatchModel()
@State var numberMatches: Int = 0

@State private var showingPopover = false


init() {
    model.getData()
    
}

var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        VStack {
            var numPlayers = String(model.match[1].numPlayers)
            Text(numPlayers)
            
            Text("Hello World")
            Text("The sport they want to play is" + model.match[0].sport)
            
            ScrollView {
                VStack() {
                    
                    
                    Button("New Post") {
                        showingPopover = true
                    }
                    .popover(isPresented: $showingPopover) {
                        newPost()
                            .font(.headline)
                            .padding()
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}

}
```

I have tested that at the end of the for loop in the model the array has all the matches and is in the Published variable but when I try to access it in the view nothing shows up in the text. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Note `getData()` is an asynchronous function, it will take time to complete.
Try using `@StateObject var model = MatchModel()` and put `model.getData()` 
in `.onAppear { model.getData() }` not in init. If that does not work try wrapping `self.match.append` in this:
`DispatchQueue.main.async { 
self.match.append(Matches(dID: document.documentID, uid: uidX, time: timeX, sport: sportX, numPlayers: numPlayersX))
}`

Comment: unfortunately none of the proposed solutions worked didn't work, and another problem has arised that it keeps throwing an "Index out of bounds index", I circumvented the problem temporarily by manually setting a few or the indexes in the array as empty strings and such so it doesn't give me an error but it still does not display the correct information.